# EF maps incorrect tables with thew new ASP Identity 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am trying to map a one-to-many relationship between users & groups. I want the users to have an individual ranking for each group they join, relative only to that group. Unfortunately EF will not map what I want, and I've been stuck trying to figure out why for 2 days.

IdentityModels.cs:

```
namespace MapGroupsToRoles.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public ApplicationUser() { this.RolesToGroups = new HashSet<GroupToRoles>(); }
        public virtual ICollection<GroupToRoles> RolesToGroups { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }
    public class GroupToRoles
    {
        public virtual int GroupToRolesId { get; set; }
        public GroupToRoles() { }
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
        public virtual ClanRole Role { get; set; }
    }
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {

        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<GroupToRoles> GroupToRolesTable { get; set; }
        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
        {
            modelbuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
        //    modelbuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().Ignore(u => u.Id);
            modelbuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(u => u.Id);           
            modelbuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(u => u.RolesToGroups).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

            modelbuilder.Entity<GroupToRoles>().ToTable("GroupToRolesTable").HasKey(u => u.GroupToRolesId);
            modelbuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(u => u.ProviderKey);
            modelbuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(u => u.RoleId);

            modelbuilder.Entity<Group>().ToTable("Groups");
            modelbuilder.Entity<Group>().HasKey(u => u.GroupId);
            modelbuilder.Entity<Group>().HasMany(u => u.Roles).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

        }
    }

}
```

Above: the important parts to note here are:

```
public class GroupToRoles
{
    public virtual int GroupToRolesId { get; set; }
    public GroupToRoles() { }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
    public virtual ClanRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public virtual ICollection<GroupToRoles> RolesToGroups { get; set; }
```

inside the ApplicationUser class.

Group.cs:

```
namespace MapGroupsToRoles.Models
{
    public class Group
    {
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public Group() { this.Roles = new HashSet<GroupToRoles>(); }
        public virtual string GroupName { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<GroupToRoles> Roles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Right, so what results am I getting? 
 1. Both Hashsets (ie the GroupToRoles sets in Group.cs and ApplicationUser do not appear...
 2. The group table displays Group_GroupId1 and Group_GroupId ... where's the 1 come from?!

Any help would be hugely appreciated!!!!

EDIT_____________

So re-iterate I want to map users to groups, where they have one role per group, and be a member of many groups. Therefore it is a map of one to many between user and "GroupToRoles" class (which in turn maps one to many groups).

Example:
John is a member of groups a,b,c
for group a he is admin, 
group b he is a member
group c he is a visitor

I don't think I can use (please correct me if im wrong) the standard ASP roles (which is why i created the "ClanRole" class, as I also want a single global role per user which will handle admin rights on the entire site (not just groups the uses have created).

Basically, I want to be able to map the ApplicationUser class to many "GroupToRoles". From there, everything else should fall into place. It is however resisting and I can't work out why!

Many thanks

Comment: I'm confused.. what do roles have to do with it?  You don't mention anything about roles in your comments... but your code is dealing with them...  I think you need to have a clear idea of how your data model is supposed to work, and you haven't explained that.  It looks like you're trying to do some bizarre kind of translation of roles to some other table, and that's just going to lead to more pain... so you need to explain clearly what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have added an edit, please let me know if this is more clear

Comment: Can a user only have one role per group?

Comment: Hi Kevin, yes but be a member of many groups.

Comment: I also want them to have 1 role in the application e.g. the actual website, which is why i went towards defining a seperate "ClanRole" class opposed to the standard IdentityRole - i am unsure if it would cause issues using the IdentityRoles for both (ideally I would but that's for future insight)

Comment: And how is ClanRole defined?

Comment: err at work, but its just a class with two strings for name and description in it.

Comment: the idea there would be that i can then just block users by searching the group roles list to see if that user is within it, as the groups wont be large

Comment: Why don't you simply use standard roles and create a unique role for each group?  If you want to use generic role names, you can just create roles like "GroupX::Administrator", and "GroupX::Member" and then in your UI filter off the "GroupX::" part.  This is far simpler, and works within the bounds of the existing system

Comment: Good. Point. :D
I assume there's not a limit on how many roles you can generate? I want a system that can extend to a huge number of users.

Comment: UPDATE: duplicate Id's where because they should be string types!!! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps required to answer this question were far more than anticipated. A guide will be wrote up within the next few weeks, and a link provided here.

A brief overview:

1. create a seperate context:add to web.config & add the following:

   ```
     public class MyContext : DbContext
     {
           public MyContext () : base("DefaultConnection")
           {
           }
           public static MyContext Create()
           {
               return new MyContext ();
           }
     }
   ```
2. Remove the ApplicationDbContext, build to quickly find where this is referenced and replace them with your new context
3. change the fluent to (put inside the context):

   ```
       public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<GroupToRoles> GroupToRolesTable { get; set; }
       public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
       public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }
       protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelbuilder)
       {
           modelbuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users");
           modelbuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasKey(u => u.Id);
           modelbuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(u => u.RolesToGroups);//.WithRequired(/*u => u.User*/).HasForeignKey(u => u.UserId);

           modelbuilder.Entity<GroupToRoles>().ToTable("GroupToRolesTable").HasKey(u => u.GroupToRolesId);

           modelbuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(u => u.ProviderKey);
           modelbuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(u => u.RoleId);

           modelbuilder.Entity<Group>().ToTable("Groups");
           modelbuilder.Entity<Group>().HasKey(u => u.GroupId);
           modelbuilder.Entity<Group>().HasMany(u => u.Roles);//.WithRequired(/*u => u.Group*/).HasForeignKey(u => u.GroupId);
       }
   ```

Comment: I'd be interested in a guide to how you solved this. I've got a similar issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24509524/adding-many-to-many-relationship-from-applicationuser-to-custom-entity)

Answer (score 0):

I really confused about your idea.

Why can one user assign many groups? (no different with role). This concept makes lots of redundant data.

I think one user shoudl only be able to assign just 1 group, 0-1 to Many.

For example: the application has 3 groups: admin, user, anonym.

- admin has all role,
- user have role 'home,usermanager, etc'
- anonym have role 'home'

You have to change the structure of the entity like this:

IdentityUser

```
public class IdentityUser<TKey, TLogin, TClaim, TGroup, TGroupRole> : IUser<TKey>
    where TLogin : IdentityUserLogin<TKey>
    where TClaim : IdentityUserClaim<TKey>
    where TGroup : IdentityGroup<TKey, TGroupRole>
    where TGroupRole : IdentityGroupRole<TKey>
{
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual bool EmailConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public virtual string SecurityStamp { get; set; }
    public virtual string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual bool PhoneNumberConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual bool TwoFactorEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? LockoutEndDateUtc { get; set; }
    public virtual bool LockoutEnabled { get; set; }
    public virtual int AccessFailedCount { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TClaim> Claims { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TLogin> Logins { get; private set; }
    public virtual TGroup Group { get; set; }
    public virtual TKey Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserName { get; set; }
    public IdentityUser()
    {
        this.Claims = new List<TClaim>();
        this.Logins = new List<TLogin>();
    }
}
```

IdentityGroup

```
public class IdentityGroup<TKey, TGroupRole> : IGroup<TKey>
    where TGroupRole : IdentityGroupRole<TKey>
{
    public IdentityGroup()
    {
        Roles = new List<TGroupRole>();
    }
    public TKey Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TGroupRole> Roles { get; private set; }
}
```

GroupRole

```
public class IdentityGroupRole<TKey>
{
    public virtual TKey RoleId { get; set; }
    public virtual TKey GroupId { get; set; }
}
```

IdentityDbContext

```
public class IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserClaim, TGroup, TGroupRole> : DbContext
    where TUser : IdentityUser<TKey, TUserLogin, TUserClaim, TGroup, TGroupRole>
    where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey, TGroupRole>
    where TUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<TKey>
    where TUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<TKey>
    where TGroup : IdentityGroup<TKey, TGroupRole>
    where TGroupRole : IdentityGroupRole<TKey>
{
    private IdentityConfiguration _config;
    public virtual IDbSet<TUser> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<TRole> Roles { get; set; }
    public virtual IDbSet<TGroup> Groups { get; set; }
    public bool RequireUniqueEmail { get; set; }
    public IdentityDbContext()
        : this("DefaultConnection", new IdentityConfiguration())
    {
    }
    public IdentityDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString)
        : this(nameOrConnectionString, new IdentityConfiguration())
    {
    }
    public IdentityDbContext(string nameOrConnectionString, IdentityConfiguration config)
        : base(nameOrConnectionString)
    {
        _config = config;
    }
    public IdentityDbContext(DbConnection existingConnection, DbCompiledModel model, bool contextOwnsConnection)
        : base(existingConnection, model, contextOwnsConnection)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("modelBuilder");
        }
        var user = modelBuilder.Entity<TUser>().ToTable(_config.UserTableName, _config.Schema);
        user.HasMany(u => u.Claims).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(uc => uc.UserId);
        user.HasMany(u => u.Logins).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ul => ul.UserId);
        user.HasOptional(u => u.Group).WithMany().Map(m => m.MapKey("GroupId"));
        user.Property(u => u.UserName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("UserNameIndex") { IsUnique = true }));

        // CONSIDER: u.Email is Required if set on options?
        user.Property(u => u.Email).HasMaxLength(256);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TGroupRole>().HasKey((TGroupRole r) => new
        {
            r.GroupId,
            r.RoleId
        }).ToTable(_config.GroupRoleTableName, _config.Schema);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TUserLogin>().HasKey((TUserLogin l) => new
        {
            l.LoginProvider,
            l.ProviderKey,
            l.UserId
        }).ToTable(_config.LoginTableName, _config.Schema);

        modelBuilder.Entity<TUserClaim>().ToTable(_config.ClaimTableName, _config.Schema);

        var role = modelBuilder.Entity<TRole>()
            .ToTable(_config.RoleTableName, _config.Schema);
        role.Property(r => r.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("RoleNameIndex") { IsUnique = true }));
        role.HasMany(r => r.Groups).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId).WillCascadeOnDelete();

        var group = modelBuilder.Entity<TGroup>()
            .ToTable(_config.GroupTableName, _config.Schema);
        group.Property(r => r.Name)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(256)
            .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("GroupNameIndex") { IsUnique = true }));
        group.HasMany(r => r.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.GroupId).WillCascadeOnDelete();
        //group.HasMany(g => g.Users).WithOptional().Map(m => m.MapKey("GroupId"));
    }
    protected override DbEntityValidationResult ValidateEntity(DbEntityEntry entityEntry, IDictionary<object, object> items)
    {
        if (entityEntry != null && entityEntry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            List<DbValidationError> list = new List<DbValidationError>();
            TUser user = entityEntry.Entity as TUser;
            if (user != null)
            {
                if (this.Users.Any((TUser u) => string.Equals(u.UserName, user.UserName)))
                {
                    list.Add(new DbValidationError("User", string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, IdentityResources.DuplicateUserName, new object[]
                    {
                        user.UserName
                    })));
                }
                if (this.RequireUniqueEmail && this.Users.Any((TUser u) => string.Equals(u.Email, user.Email)))
                {
                    list.Add(new DbValidationError("User", string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, IdentityResources.DuplicateEmail, new object[]
                    {
                        user.Email
                    })));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                TRole role = entityEntry.Entity as TRole;
                if (role != null && this.Roles.Any((TRole r) => string.Equals(r.Name, role.Name)))
                {
                    list.Add(new DbValidationError("Role", string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, IdentityResources.RoleAlreadyExists, new object[]
                    {
                        role.Name
                    })));
                }
            }
            if (list.Any<DbValidationError>())
            {
                return new DbEntityValidationResult(entityEntry, list);
            }
        }
        return base.ValidateEntity(entityEntry, items);
    }
}
```

i just finish my library, full source you can download [here](https://github.com/aiska/Identity.GroupBaseEF)

or you can add library via nuget [here](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Identity.GroupEF/)